# Editing an android screen capture video in blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I recently started video editing with the video editing function in blender. 
Until now there was no problem, but today I made a screen capturing video on my android phone using the play store application AZ screen recorder. I transfered the video to my computer an imported it into blender.  The video is a mp4 file  1920x1080 p 30fps  and about 1 minute long, but after importing the video sequence editor showed over 6000000 frames.

After closing blender rebooting my computer and updating blender I tried importing the video again.  Now the VSE says my video is only about 1800 frames long  -  so that is good,  but if I want to play the video and watch it in the VSE preview window it seams frozen. I can hear the audio but the video isn't playing.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does any other player have similar behaviour with that video? Could you post a sample of the video? Maybe it's just a matter of hardware limitation.

Comment: Most likely the video was recorded using some form of variable frame rate. Blender does not support that. Transcode your video first into a constant frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to change video format before importing to blender? Idk in which format the app is recording the video file, maybe this may cause issues. :)

Comment: I'm going to try this, but it's just a mp4 file

Comment: Yay, but mp4 is only a container file and not a video file itself so maybe try change to flv, wmv and also mp4 just to be tried. :)

Comment: I converted it to mp4 and it's working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm happy for you that it worked :)